# Perl - find the highest value in file by two factors

Tags: perl

I have a file and I need to read it in to Perl, find all the total number of births with my name and year of birth and then find the states with the highest and lowest numbers of birth for my name and year.  I can do the first part, but I am completely lost when it comes to trying to find the highest and lowest states by year and DOB.  How do I match and keep track of this?
Here is the code I have so far:

```
use 5.13.0;
use warnings;
use strict;

my $file;
my $line;
my $count = 0;
my $total;
my $name;
my $year, my $gender;
my $state;

$file = "StateNames.csv";

open( FILE, "$file" );
while ( $line = <FILE> ) {
   if ( $line =~ /Paul,1982/ ) {
      ( $line, $name, $year, $gender, $state, $total ) = split /,/, $line;
      $count = $count + $total;
   }
}

if ( $count == 0 ) {
   print
     "There were no people named Paul found.        Please       try again.";
}

print "The total number of people named Paul born in 1982 is $count";
print $state $total;
```

File

```
406738 Pilar 1964 F CA 8
406739 Piper 1964 F CA 8
406740 Raelynn 1964 F CA 8
406741 Rafaela 1964 F CA 8
406742 Reba 1964 F CA 8
406743 Risa 1964 F CA 8
406744 Robbi 1964 F CA 8
406745 Rolanda 1964 F CA 8
```

Comment: The data is in a CSV file formatted as per below.   I need to find the state highest number of births by name and year                      406738 Pilar 1964 F CA 8
406739 Piper 1964 F CA 8
406740 Raelynn 1964 F CA 8
406741 Rafaela 1964 F CA 8
406742 Reba 1964 F CA 8
406743 Risa 1964 F CA 8
406744 Robbi 1964 F CA 8
406745 Rolanda 1964 F CA 8

Comment: Hint: a database would be a good option. A hash would be another option.

Comment: The `/.../` bit is a [regular expression](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html), with specific rules of use.  You want `/Paul\s+1982/`, or rather with variables `/$n\s+\$y/` (pick better names though).  That will match lines that have `Paul` followed by at least one "space" (tab included) followed by `1982`

Comment: Maybe you need to define some variables to save lowest and highest numbers and states and use them in the loop.

Answer (score 0):

You want to put your data in multiple hashes.  This would be a start:

```
my %parsedInfo;

my @info;
my $i = 1;
while (defined (my $line = <DATA>)) {
    my ($lineNumber, $name, $year, $gender, $state, $total)
        = @info = split /\s+/, $line;
    push @{$parsedInfo{$name}{$year}{$state}}, [@info];
}
foreach my $name (sort keys %parsedInfo) {
    my $yearRef = $parsedInfo{$name};
    foreach my $year (sort {$a <=> $b} keys %$yearRef) {
        my $stateRef = $yearRef->{$year};
        foreach my $state (sort keys %$stateRef) {
            print "$name=>$year=>$state ==========\n";
            for my $infoRef (@{$parsedInfo{$name}{$year}{$state}}) {
                print join(':', @$infoRef), "\n";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Output looks like this

```
Pilar=>1964=>CA ==========
406738:Pilar:1964:F:CA:8
Piper=>1964=>CA ==========
406739:Piper:1964:F:CA:8
Raelynn=>1964=>CA ==========
406740:Raelynn:1964:F:CA:8
Rafaela=>1964=>CA ==========
406741:Rafaela:1964:F:CA:8
Reba=>1964=>CA ==========
406742:Reba:1964:F:CA:8
Risa=>1964=>CA ==========
406743:Risa:1964:F:CA:8
Robbi=>1964=>CA ==========
406744:Robbi:1964:F:CA:8
Rolanda=>1964=>CA ==========
406745:Rolanda:1964:F:CA:8
```

This creates a hash keyed to the name that contains a hash keyed to the year which contains a hash keyed to the state which contains the data for that entry.

Once you have it in the appropriate hash you can do whatever you want.  Put it in the debugger and step through it for a better understanding.  Without better data I can't do much more.

Hope this helps...
Steve S.